# loading incomplete csv data with load data local infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv, file-upload

I have been trying to load data from a csv to my mysql database using LOAD DATA INFILE. One of the columns has a lot of empty cells. When I try to select non empty cells using where column<>'' the result shows all the rows instead of just non empty ones. The data is a mix of numbers and string and column data type is varchar. When I do a search with column!=0, all the numeric data is displayed. I know the data is present because when I do Select Distinct I can see all the values(but just once as is supposed to be). How do I select all the non empty cells. Code for uploading is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
    INTO TABLE '.$table.'
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
```

Comment: Try `column is not null`

Comment: Also please show us the table definition.